# {caching} issue in smarty login form

Tags: php, caching, smarty

Again I'm stuck with Smarty,
In a project that I'm work on, I have a register/login forms
in login for example, when I try to enter a specific "user/pass" an sql query is being proceed
but the problem:

Smarty is keeping caching an old template, i.e: "Wrong username or password"
I mean in simple words, php is working fine at the back, but the template are retrieved from previous caching!!

one more example, I have at the footer "Login" form, you enter the data, the script check your permissions and send you to the control panel, now at the control panel the , I made a check in the "footer" so if the user is logged just gimme back something else like, "Welcome user" but the script is not acting like that at the contrary it still bringing back the "login" form no matter the data entered were correct or incorrect!!

I hope I made it clear!!

I've told to change the chaching per every template to 0

```
$smarty->caching = 0;
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
```

====================================================

Here is the footer.tpl:

```
<footer class="page_row">
    <div id="footer3">
//If the user is logged in
        {if isset($smarty.session.logged) && $smarty.session.logged == true} 
        <span style='text-align:left; float:left; margin:4px;'>Login:</span>
        <a href=index.php?do=members_panel&id=$md>{$smarty.session.name}</a></br>
        <a href='index.php?do=logout'>Logout</a>

        {else} //if the user is not logged in
            <span style="text-align:left; float:left; margin:4px;">Login:</span>
            <table width="20px" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <form name="sign_in" method="POST" action="index.php?do=sign_in">
            <tr><td><input name="username" type="text" class="textfield" id="username" placeholder="Username"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" placeholder="Password"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn-style" value="Sign in"></td></tr>
        </table>
        {/if}
    </div>
```

and here the PHP part:

```
elseif ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'sign_in') { //Sign_in page
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db_handle, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db_handle, $_POST['password']);

$login_sql = "SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
$login_query = mysqli_query($db_handle, $login_sql) or die("Bad Query: " . mysqli_error($db_handle));

if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_handle) == 1) {
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_query) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db_handle));
$_SESSION['logged'] == true;
$_SESSION['name'] = $user['Name'];

$smarty->assign('NAME', $user['Name']);
$smarty->assign('PASSWORD', $user['Password']);
$smarty->assign('EMAIL', $user['Email']);
$smarty->caching = 0;
$smarty->display('login_good.tpl');

}
```

Again, the problem is that the .tpl part is not being changed after I check if the user logged or not!
P.S: the (footer.tpl) "which has the form login" is included in all files such as the one shown in the upper code "login_good.tpl"

Comment: Remove just in case your files in cache folder and make sure new don't appear there. You should also prepare some test code to look at it, now without any code it's hard to say if it's caching issue or you are doing something wrong. Let's say you assign in PHP to variable $x value 3 and you assign and display it in Smarty and now you change it to 22. When you refresh your page you have still 3?

Comment: I've tried to remove the files from the cache, but that did not work, plus I'm giving the caching = 0; so I believe that will refresh the files in each visit, I'll update the question with php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
$_SESSION['logged'] == true;
```

Here you don't make assignment but just comparison, it should be:

```
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
```

So the issue has nothing in common with Smarty caching but just for using PHP operators

Comment: Opaaaaa ))) thank you alot, one more time you've helped ME in my problems to find the solution )) now it works properly but I still have one more question, does using the module caching = 0; is just for testing use?? the pages worked all properly after adding this command but still the main page does not apply the change (changing the form of logging in to Welcome message) yet I add the code (caching = 0;) I hope it is clear!

Comment: You normally don't use caching in Smarty. It's quite advanced feature definitely not for beginners. By default Smarty caching is set to false and you should not enable it unless you really know what you are doing.